# How to hide the NEXT button on particular sliders

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap carousel and i want to hide the NEXT button on particular sliders with quiz questions. If the JavaScript validation on the HTML quiz passes, the carousel will then  cycle to the next image slider and the NEXT button should reappear. Im not good with JavaScript and angular.

This is the script that i tried to use to hide the NEXT button on slider 5 and 8.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 $('.prev-slide').hide();

 $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
 var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
 var currentIndex = carouselData.getActiveIndex();

 if (currentIndex = 5 && 8) {
 $('.prev-slide').show();
 }
 else {
 $('.next-slide').hide();
 }

 })


</script>
```

This is an overview of my carousel html.

```
<div id = "myCarousel" class = "carousel slide" data-interval="false" >
  <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class = "carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active           </li>
     <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
     <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
       ...
     <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "19"></li>
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "20"></li>
 </ol>  

 <!-- Carousel items -->
 <div class = "carousel-inner">
  <div class = "item active">
     <img src = "includes/modules/sliders/Business_planning_for_success/Slide1.JPG" alt = "slide">
  </div>
  <div class = "item">
      <img src = "includes/modules/sliders/Business_planning_for_success/Slide2.JPG" alt = "slide">
  </div>
  ....
   <div class = "item">
       <img src =  "includes/modules/sliders/Business_planning_for_success/Slide21.JPG" alt =  "slide">
   </div>

</div>

   <!-- Controls buttons -->
   <div style = "text-align:center;">
     <input type = "button" class = "btn-sm prev-slide" onclick="slide()" value = "Previous Slide">
     <input type = "button" class = "btn-sm next-slide" onclick="slide()" value = "Next Slide">
   </div>
```

This is the JavaScript for the slider buttons

```
function slide() {

// Cycles to the previous item
 $(".prev-slide").click(function() {
 $("#myCarousel").carousel('prev');
 });

// Cycles to the next item
 $(".next-slide").click(function() {
 $("#myCarousel").carousel('next');
});

};
```

Please help.

Comment: Just off the top of it, condition should be  if ((currentIndex == 5) &&(currentIndex == 8)) {

Comment: thanx. thats helps.

Comment: ....but still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:`<input type = "button" id="prevBtn" class = "btn-sm prev-slide" onclick="slide()" style="display:none;" value = "Previous Slide">`

and in js:`if (currentIndex== 5 && currentIndex==  8) {document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display="block"; }`

Comment: thanks very much. but it has hidden the PREV button on all the slides. its not changing according to the sliders.

Comment: @tendaitakas That's because `currentIndex` can only hold one integer at a time. It can't be both `5` and `8`. Did you mean _OR_? For example `if (currentIndex == 5 || currentIndex == 8)`?

Comment: thanks but still its not working. maybe its where i have put it. should the script be put in the slide() function, because that where i have put it.